# Llist all the operations(Requests) from a wsdl url using Java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, soap, webservice-client

Is there a way to list all the operations from a wsdl url(by specifying end point and not from the xml) using Java?

Below is a sample endpoint.
http://www.webservicemart.com/uszip.asmx?WSDL

Please help.

Comment: have a look to this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/soa-model/OKQBRoY9H8I

Answer (score 2):

you can use [eviware/soapui's API](https://github.com/SmartBear/soapui) for that.

You can create an interface with the designated WSDL, then use it to fetch operations.

```
    int operationCount = wsdlInterface.getOperationCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < operationCount; i++){

        WsdlOperation wsdlOperation = wsdlInterface.getOperationAt(i);
        String operationName = wsdlOperation.getName();
        // you can use this name, add to an arraylist etc.

        allOperations.add(wsdlOperation);

        WsdlTestCase testCase = generateTestCase(wsdlTestSuite, operationName);
        WsdlTestStep testStep = generateTestStep(wsdlOperation, testCase, operationName);

    }
```

Documentation goes here:

https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/allclasses-noframe.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use XPath to grab the  tags:
[XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp)

```
<wsdl:binding name="USZipSoap" type="tns:USZipSoap">
<soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<wsdl:operation name="ValidateZip">
<soap:operation soapAction="http://webservicemart.com/ws/ValidateZip" style="document"/>
<wsdl:input>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:input>
<wsdl:output>
<soap:body use="literal"/>
</wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
```

Using the xpath expression:

```
//wsdl:operation
```

should return you all the nodes. A xpath lib for Java would be [Jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/)

I hope that helps you further.

Thanks
Patrick

Comment: Thanks Patrick. But I want to specify the end point only, I don't want to give the wsdl/xml. Just by specifying wsdl url, Can I achieve this?